# Form reset and programmatically set values

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, reset

I am trying to reset a form using:

```
myForm.reset();
```

I tried to set values that way:

```
//solved by setting $('#myTextControl').attr('defaultValue', 'my initial value');
//Thanks RobG
$('#myTextControl').val('my value');
$('#myTextControl').attr('value', 'my value');

//solved by setting $('#myTextControl').attr('defaultChecked', false or true); initially
$('#myCheckboxControl')attr('checked', 'checked');    


//Finally it works with radios too, as shown here -> http://jsfiddle.net/4VAkp/2/
$('#myRadioControl')attr('checked', 'checked');
```

The way you update a value is important, as you can see here -> http://jsfiddle.net/4VAkp/3/
Updating a value using attr will fix the value as the default:
**Wrong**

```
radio2.attr('checked', true);
text2.attr('value', 'my text2');
```

This will not set the value as the default (as expected):
**Correct**

```
radio.prop('checked', true);
text.val('my text');
```

This works fine when the values were set by a user, but don't work if values were set programmatically.

If I set a value programmatically first, then through the ui and finally reset it, it comes back to the programmatically set on.

I suspect that there should be a way to set a value programmatically without changing the default.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance,

Eric

Comment: How are you setting the value programmatically? Please provide a code sample.

Comment: add your sample code for more clarifications..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resetting the form sets the controls to their default value, which is either specified by the *value* attribute or set by the *defaultValue* property. Changes by the user do not change either of these—except in (older?) IE, where *getAttribute* is buggy.

To "reset" the form to some other set of values without modifying ether the value attribute or the defaultValue property, the *value* property of the controls must be programmatically set.

Comment: setting defaultValue works for input/text. Thanks for that!
Is there a defaultChecked or something like this for checkboxes/radios?